# What does it mean to 'fix' an element of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Statement: Let $A$ be an ideal of $F[x]$, where $F$ is a field.  Fix a nonzero element $g(x) \in A$ of the smallest degree.  Then $A = \langle g(x) \rangle $.

I'm not super familiar with the term 'fix' so I don't entirely know what this means and how I proceed with the proof.  If it's fixed in $A$, does that mean any element in $A$ is a multiple of $g(x)$?

Thank you!

Comment: It is equivalent to saying "Let $g(x)$ be a non-zero element of $A$ of the smallest degree".

Comment: You may see it as synonymous with "consider".

Comment: It means don't change which element you have chosen throughout the discussion

Comment: we use the term "fix" here to mean that we're picking some $g(x)\in A$, and for the rest of our discussion, we're going to leave this unaltered in any way. So we're not going to change notation or anything. In that sense it is "fixed once and for all" in the beginning of the proof up to the end. It's just a way of setting the notation for the rest of the proof.

Comment: @BubbyNX In mathematical argumentation one uses the syntagm *"fix a $t$ such that $P(t)$"* after having rigorously established *the existence of such a $t$* (in other words after having proved the relation $(\exists t)P$) and proceeds therefore to consider one such $t$ that was already shown to exist. From the technical point of view, how this term $t$ is introduced intimately depends on the details of the formal language one uses to express mathematics. The fact that it is fixed means that it is a not variable that would be susceptible to quantification.

Comment: One of the meanings of "fix" is "decide or settle on (a specific price, date, course of action, etc.)". Here it means simply that since $\,A\neq (0)\,$ (missing hypothesis) the set of nonzero elements of $A$ is nonempty so we can choose one of least degree. The point is that nonzero ideals in Euclidean domains are generated by *any* element $0\neq g\in A$ of least Euclidean size (here degree), since the remainder of every element mod $g$ must be $0$ (else it would be smaller than $g)\ \ $

Comment: I usually associate "fix" with "select", I also agree with the previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fix" in this context is synonymous with "choose an arbitrary". So, the problem statement could be rephrased as:

> Let $A$ be an ideal of $F[x]$, where $F$ is a field. Then for every nonzero element $g \in A$ of smallest degree, we have $A = \langle g \rangle$.

Or, a bit more formally, making the quantifiers in the first sentence more explicit:

> For every field $F$, every ideal $A$ of $F[x]$, and every nonzero element $g \in A$ such that the degree of $g$ is minimal among nonzero elements of $A$, we have $A = \langle g \rangle$.

(Of course, there are some more quantifiers implicit in the conclusion "$A = \langle g \rangle$", but I'm just highlighting the general structure of the statement. The point is that "Let ... be a", "where ... is a", and "Fix ..." are all phrases that can be used to indicate a universal quantifier.)

Comment: Upon a careful analysis of the nuances and the actual logico-deductive processes involved, the phrase "fix" you mention in your last sentence doesn't necessarily indicate universal quantification. Particularly in a context such as the one proposed by the OP above the mentioned phrase actually refers to existential **de**quantification.